# How to make Wireless AP accessible (local server) without internet connection?

Tags: wifi, dhcp, router, hostapd, isc-dhcpd

Using `hostapd` and `dhcpd`, I was able to turn my raspberry Pi into a hotspot/router. It works fine, but I want to know how to make it accessible (via wifi) when it's disconnected from the internet. I have a webserver serving local apps. I want to wireless access locally running apps being served that don't require internet connection. If I try to connect to the router from any computer or smartphone while it's offline, I'll get the "No Internet Connection" and it won't resolve.

Comment: It's hard to give you an answer without knowing the details of what you have now.  The standard solution is to make a separate network for mobiles (as opposed to bridging between wifi and wired).  You'll need a DHCP server and a DNS server (perhaps `unbound`) for this network.  An NTP server and something like `avahi` would be nice, but not essential.

Comment: Would you tell us where there are iPhones or Mac involved? ....Please add the technical details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) tool features you can create an AP without Internet connection to share your files:

Install `create_ap`:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install
```

> AP without Internet sharing:

```
create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

You can transfert your file from the remote server through `ssh` using an android app.

The server should be connected to a wifi **AP without Internet connexion** ( router ....)

The Android device should be connected to the AP ( created through the `create_ap` command)

On your rpi install and configure the ssh server

```
apt install openssh-server
```

Open the `sshd_config`

```
nano  /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Add / verify the following

```
AllowUsers Your_username_here
PermitRootLogin no
Port 22
```

Restart the service:

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Install an android application e,g: [JuiceSSH - SSH Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh&hl=en).... to access your server.

Comment: Awesome, I was able to run the AP without internet sharing command and connect successfully from iPhone. That last missing piece is my accessing the local app(s) running on the AP from the iPhone browser. I tried navigating the the AP's IP address with no luck

Comment: @Ricky Brown Are you able to use android , i can update my answer

Comment: No I was unsuccessful with android, your update will be most welcome!